# Two Minipages, two times itemize - how to correct alignment

Tags: align, itemize, minipage

I wanted to use a minipage to reduce the size of my itemize list

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item e
        \item f
        \item g
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

unfortunately i have an uneven number of entries and get the "error", that the second minipage starts its first item on the height of the second item of the first minipage....

so "e" is on the height of "b" while I want it to be at the same height as "a".

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `[t]` position specifier instead of `[b]` and also don't leave blank lines before and after `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item e
        \item f
        \item g
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution with `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
\columnbreak
        \item e
        \item f
        \item g
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Putting `\raggedcolumns` before `\begin{multicols}` like

```
\raggedcolumns
\begin{multicols}{2}
```

gives

[image]

And using `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\textbullet}X!{\textbullet}X}
         a & e \\
         b & f \\
         c & g \\
         d &
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And finally using `enumitem` for its inline list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=*, itemjoin={{\qquad}}]
        \item a thing
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
        \item g
    \end{itemize*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can save more space.